# Obtaining Square Cell List from table given 2 cell elements

Tags: javascript

Given a 2 cell elements, my goal is to obtain an array of elements to form a square between those 2 cells as the image follows:

[image]

Im tryng to build this on plain javascript.

The main problem is identifiyng the min/max cells ,specially when i have rowSpans and colSpans

I made the following code, that works when then is no spans !

```
makeSquareSelection(cell1, cell2) {

  const table = cell1.closest("table");

  const x1 = cell1.cellIndex;
  const y1 = cell1.parentNode.rowIndex;

  const x2 = cell2.cellIndex;
  const y2 = cell2.parentNode.rowIndex;

  const minX = Math.min(x1, x2);
  const minY = Math.min(y1, y2);

  let maxX = Math.max(x1, x2);
  let maxY = Math.max(y1, y2);

  console.log("MINX " + minX);
  console.log("MAXX " + maxX);
  console.log("MINY " + minY);
  console.log("MAXY " + maxY);

  for (let y = minY; y <= maxY; y++) {

     for (let x = minX; x <= maxX; x++) {

        console.log("Selecting " + x + " - " + y);

        const cell = table.rows[y].cells[x];
        this.state.selectedCells.push(cell);
        cell.className += "selectedCell";

     }

  }
```

}

Fiddle Demonstrating the issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/h63ojct6/5/

How could this be solved when i have colSpans and rowSpans ?

Thanks !

Comment: please share html code as well

Comment: added the html and a fiddle demonstrating the issue

Comment: in case of rowspan and colspan, how the selection should look  because above mentioned screenshots are without rowspan or colspan

Comment: should select aways a square.

Comment: if there is colapn or rowspan , it should be ignored ??

Comment: not ignored, the missing tds should be added to match them and aways make a square or rectangular selection.